# Nested slot tags inside synthetic shadow

Tags: shadow-dom, slots

We try to test automatically our Sales Force application via Playwrigth.But to steer page components we'd like to fully understand synthetic Shadow polyfill.

How it's possible to have 2 synthetic nested slots?
We have seen in a page source code things like:

```
<a records-hoverablelink_hoverablelink="" class="flex-wrap-ie11" href="/lightning/r/User/00520000001UL5TAAW/view" tabindex="0">
<slot records-hoverablelink_hoverablelink="">
 <slot force-lookup_lookup=""><span force-lookup_lookup="">XXXXXXXXX</span>
 </slot>
 </slot>
</a>
```

I understand for 1 level slot. But I can't realize what type of component can generate this situation.
Thanks!